# C# WPF populating a datagrid combobox column from SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I am writing a C# program that will populate that DataGrid. I would also like it to populate the column I have a combobox in. I have the selection list part of the combobox working correctly I just cannot populate that column with data from the database. I think I'm really close I just cant figure out what I'm missing.

Here's the XAML I've come up with so far.

```
<Window x:Class="datagridcombobox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:datagridcombobox"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <DataGrid AlternatingRowBackground="#FFC4B0B0" Height="200" Width="500"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="grdEmployee" Margin="2,0,1,-81">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Terminal" x:Name="comboboxColumn1"  SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Terminal}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Terminal}" Width="100" Header="Terminal"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Applicator}" Width="100" Header="Applicator"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding applicator_Type}" Width="100" Header="Applicator Type"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Hand_tool}" Width="100" Header="Hand Tool"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Hand_Tool_Type}" Width="100" Header="Hand Tool Type"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Wire_Gauge}" Width="100" Header="Wire Gauge"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# code

```
{
    DataTable Lds;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    SqlConnection connection;

    public List<string> GVComboBox { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Step1()
    {
        Common.sqlApplicator = "Select Terminal,Applicator,applicator_Type,Hand_tool, Hand_Tool_Type ,Wire_Gauge,Crimp_Height as 'Core Crimp Height',Conductor_Crimp_Width as 'Core Crimp Width',Insulator_Crimp_Height as 'Insulation Crimp Height',Insulator_Crimp_Width as 'Insulation Crimp Width',Tooling,Notes,Strip_Length as 'Strip Length',Applicator_Status as 'Applicator Status' ,ID from Tooling_Specs where Applicator like '2151526-1%' order by Applicator";

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Common.sqlApplicator, connection);
            Lds = new DataTable("Applicator");
            adapter.Fill(Lds);
            grdEmployee.ItemsSource = Lds.DefaultView;

        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        };

        GVComboBox = new List<string>() { "CRV Owned", "Customer Owned", "CRV Leased", "Customer Leased", "" };
        comboboxColumn1.ItemsSource = GVComboBox;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString);
        Step1();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no error. I get the drop down with what I want. But I want to populate that field with data from the database if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM YourDataBase", yourConnectionName);
SqlDataReader read = null;
read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(read.Read())
{
    YourComboBox.Items.Add(read["YourValue"].ToString() + "read["value1"].ToString()+ "StringValue"); 
}
read.Close();
```

Comment: You can improve the quality of your Answer by more clearly identifying where in their code they should place your Answer.  Please also include an explanation of what you think their problem was and how your solution fixes that.  Please include links and author names to any reference sources that proved to be relevant to your Answer.

Comment: I believe it is not a good idea to Add to the Items but rather set DataSource to some observable collection